# CP IAM Role condition based on part of resource name with extract function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

resource.name.extract('/instances/{name}/').startsWith('-prod-')

Since we can use this way to extract name of a instance which starts with example.

**Similarly i want to know whether I can extract name for namespace which is in Kubernetes.**

resource.name.extract('/namespaces/{name}/').startsWith('-prod-')

I'm expecting a details whether this condition will work or not for namespaces.
resource.name.extract('/namespaces/{name}/').startsWith('-prod-')